# The spawnSync function in child_process does not return anything

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

- VSCode Version: 1.13.1
- OS Version: Win 10 Pro  1703   15063.413

Now my vscode can not debug, press the F5 still have this problem [#26628](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26628) 
I think it is possible that the spawnSync function in child_process is not working properly.
[some clues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4ozF.png)

I tried installing different versions of node.js, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('node -v', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: In fact, the image in the clue is the code in the following file
`C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft VS Code \ resources \ app \ extensions \ ms-vscode.node-debug \ out \ node \ extension.js`. Is the code in the vscode installation file. I want to find out why my vscode has been the reason for the collapse. [See this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26628) and [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29230)